# Automapper - Mapping entity types to nested view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Lets say I have an EF entity like this:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Psuedonym { get; set; }
    public bool HasPsuedonym { get; set; }
}
```

From this entity I want to map to a viewmodel which looks like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PsuedonymViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Which contains this other view model:

```
public class PsuedonymViewModel 
{
    public string Psuedonym { get; set; }
    public bool HasPsuedonym { get; set; }
}
```

What mappings do I need to setup?

I have a generic mapping setup which creates the following mappings:

```
Person > PersonViewModel - memberlist.dest
PersonViewModel > Person - memberlist.source

PsuedonymViewModel > Person - memberlist.dest
Person > PsuedonymViewModel - memberlist.source
```

The generic mappings only map the properties which are present in the source or destination, depending on which way the mapping is so that I don't have to add a whole bunch of ignores in manually for properties which don't match.

When I have this setup, automapper says:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following property on MyApplication.PsuedonymViewModel cannot be mapped: 
    Psuedonym 
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type MyApplication.PsuedonymViewModel.
Context:
    Mapping to property Psuedonym from System.String to MyApplication.PsuedonymViewModel
```

I understand this message as when trying to map to `PsuedonymViewModel` from the `Person` entity there is no mapping from `string` to `Psuedonym`. I can solve this with a manual mapping like this:

```
CreateMap<string, PsuedonymViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.HasPsuedonym, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.Psuedonym, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y));
```

Whilst this maps the `Psuedonym` property I have to ignore the `HasPsuedonym` property which is not what I'm after, but because it's mapping from `string` there isn't anything else I can work with.

It feels like I've done something basic wrong here but I can't figure it out, any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `Person` to build `PsuedonymViewModel` as well as `PersonViewModel` you have to build both mappings, and in root object mapping just point to build the property from the same source object:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Person, PsuedonymViewModel>();
cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x=>x.Psuedonym, m=>m.MapFrom(p=>p));
```

Comment: This is correct, in the end I added an interface to the Psuedonym model which I could use to identify the properties which needed a root mapping as you describe.